# Can a private key enumeration attack be used to steal bitcoins?

Tags: security, attack

Let's consider the following algorithm

- enumerate all of the private keys
- for each of the enumerated private keys, generate the relative public key and verify whether there is any unspent coin associated with that public key
- if there is any unspent coin, transfer those coins to an address owned by the attacker

Would an attack like this work?

Comment: Search on the internet about http://directory.io

Comment: I suggest to rephrase the question and spawn it as a new one. Try the following "What are possible mass private key attacks hardware wise in 2017-2018". Or in other words, provide me with a decent hardware funding and ill show that more is possible than expected , may others outline whats possible in detail, for example how many keys could a multi raid cluster with top notch hardware import / vanitygen, scan existing adresses with bitcoin-abe for example. - guess those who could arent bored enough to write here but write their own code :)